# Excel Spreadsheet macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am generating a text file from the Excel spreadsheet by using the following **excel macro**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteToTextFile()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'better by its name: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Open "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\123.txt" For Output As #1

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow
        Dim OutputLine As String

        Dim iCol As Long
        For iCol = 1 To LastCol
            If iCol = 1 Then 'first column (is different)
                OutputLine = ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Text
            Else 'append other columns
                OutputLine = OutputLine & "," & ws.Cells(1, iCol).Text & ": " & ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Text
            End If
        Next iCol
        'Debug.Print OutputLine
        Print #1, OutputLine 'output the full line to the text file
    Next iRow

    Close #1
    Shell "notepad.exe ""C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\123.txt""", vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Sample Excel Spreadsheet data as follows

```
ID1 | ID2 |ID3
97  | 12  | 47
08  | 09  | 54
17  | 46  | 07
```

My final output is

```
97,ID2: 12,ID3: 47
08,ID2: 09,ID3: 54
17,ID2: 46,ID3: 07
```

At my final output, I am unable to get the rows data (headings; refer below sample). Can anyone help me with this?

```
ID1,ID2,ID3
97,ID2: 12,ID3: 47
08,ID2: 09,ID3: 54
17,ID2: 46,ID3: 07
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @M.Schalk always declaring variables is the best practice actually. Also, declaring variables outside the loop is not necessary. `Dim` statements aren't executed.

Comment: Right then, thanks for the feedback. Comment's deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Updated as the previous answer did not solve the problem.

This loop was tested on sample data and should work as intended:

```
    For iCol = 1 To LastCol
        If iRow = 1 Then
            If OutputLine = vbNullString Then
                OutputLine = ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Text
            Else
                OutputLine = OutputLine & ", " & ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Text
            End If
        ElseIf iCol = 1 Then 'first column (is different)
            OutputLine = ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Text
        Else 'append other columns
            OutputLine = OutputLine & "," & ws.Cells(1, iCol).Text & ": " & ws.Cells(iRow, iCol).Text
        End If
    Next iCol
```

Comment: Well, try your suggestion on on the code above using the example data and you will see that it does not generate the desired output. Therefore the answer doesn't solve the question or/and is not useful.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Fair enough, and you're right. I took a look at some sample data and updated my answer to produce the desired output.

Comment: @well structure looks a bit odd to me but actually it works. My suggestion would have been just adding one line `Print #1 Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(1, LastCol)).Value)), ",")` right before the first `For iRow` loop (of the original code).

Comment: That would have been more elegant. It did feel a bit wonky while writing it, but my experience in handling outputs to different file formats is limited tbh, so I held on to what I understand. Feel free to post it as an answer and receive my upvote :)

Comment: Nah, the OP was a way too lazy and didn't even try anything at all when I asked him to (and I already wrote the complete code in the question above, so that was already more than he could expect here). If he shows no effort I'm not going to. • Actually I just wanted to show **you** an alternative way because I felt a bit strange seeing that `If … ElseIf` constuct wich needs to run on every column *and* row (even if it is only needed for the first row) which might make it slow (but I didn't test, just looks like).

Comment: I just read through the previous question you linked, OP does indeed seem lazy. Thank you for your input, always looking to improve!